# How can I pause program execution for one second in Perl?

Tags: perl

Could anyone show me an example of how to pause for one second in Perl? I am trying the sleep command and it isn't working.

Comment: How are you using the `sleep` function? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

$| = 1; # Disable output buffering

for (1..10) {
        print '.';
        sleep 1;
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: You don't need both warnings and diagnostics - one or the other is sufficient.  (Diagnostics means give more verbose descriptiosn of the warnings.)

Comment: `diagnostics` is useful for new users.

Answer (score 14):

[`sleep(1)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) will do exactly that.  If it's "not working" then you are measuring something incorrectly.  (That or you're not passing the right arguments -- showing us your code would be helpful.)

```
$ time perl -e 'sleep(1)'

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you guys, that's obviously not the way.

```
select undef, undef, undef, 1;
```

Comment: "sleep" is easier to use. "select" was used to sleep for less than one second a long, long, long time ago when Time::HiRes did not exist.

Comment: I forget sarcasm is always lost on the internet :P

Comment: There is more than one way to do anything in Perl :D

Answer (score 2):

This is the direct answer, which I provide just in case there was some problem with the asker's original code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 print "Hello World.\n";
 sleep 1;
```